# how to extract i2c address from i2cdetect console output

Tags: i2c

I am new to linux environment, but due to my new project I am learning and I love it, (coming from vxwork era). Now my question is How can I filter I2c address from this command "i2cdetect" using bash script. I have heard that I can use either SED or AWKD to scan and search text. 
so basically I want to get each i2c address, like these 0c, 5b, 5c, UU, 6e, 6f.

I thank you any clue or help I get.

root@plnx_aarch64:/# i2cdetect -y -r 3
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f

00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 0c -- -- --

10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 5b 5c -- -- --

60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 6e 6f

70: UU -- -- -- -- -- -- --

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to do this. I'm not sure if there is a better way, but this does seem to work.

```
import re

def get_addresses(i2cdetect_output):
    ''' Takes output from i2cdetect and extracts the addresses
        for the entries.
    '''

    # Get the rows, minus the first one
    i2cdetect_rows = i2cdetect_output.split('\r\n')[1:]
    i2cdetect_matrix = []

    # Add the rows to the matrix without the numbers and colon at the beginning
    for row in i2cdetect_rows:
        i2cdetect_matrix.append(filter(None, re.split(' +', row))[1:])

    # Add spaces to the first and last rows to make regularly shaped matrix
    i2cdetect_matrix[0] = ['  ', '  ', '  '] + i2cdetect_matrix[0]
    i2cdetect_matrix[7] = i2cdetect_matrix[7][:-1] + ['  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ', '  ']


    # Make a list of the addresses present
    address_list = []
    for i in range(len(i2cdetect_matrix)):
        for j in range(len(i2cdetect_matrix[i])):
            if i2cdetect_matrix[i][j] not in ('  ', '--', 'UU'):
                address_list.append(str(i) + str(format(j, 'x')))
            if i2cdetect_matrix[i][j] == 'UU':
                address_list.append('UU')

    return address_list
```

Comment: I'ma steal your function!

Answer (score 0):

```
   i2cdetect_hex_regex = re.compile(r'[0-9A-Fa-f]{2} ')
   @staticmethod
   def i2c_address_list() -> list:
      from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
      
      process = Popen(args=['/usr/sbin/i2cdetect', '-y', '1'], stdout=PIPE)
      stdout, _ = process.communicate()
      process.terminate()
      stdout = stdout.decode('ascii')
      
      address_list = I2C.i2cdetect_hex_regex.findall(stdout)
      address_list = [int(x.strip(), base=16) for x in address_list]
      
      return address_list
```

---

Try this one on for size!  It also shows how to run the i2c detect command (assuming you don't need sudo; which worked for my case).  As you can see the hexes in the i2cdetect output are uniquely of the form "HH " (notice the space char). The ones on the column have a ":" there instead of space so it shouldn't pick those up.